# RPM installation headerRead failed: region trailer: BAD

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6, rpm, jenkins

So I am trying to create my first rpm and am using jenkins to automate the job.

The command I am using to create the rpm is fpm and is as follows:

`+ fpm --before-install script/beforeInstall.sh --after-install script/afterInstall.sh --after-remove script/afterRemove.sh --before-remove script/beforeRemove.sh -s dir -t rpm -n gs-dashboards -v 1.0.2 -C ./build
{:timestamp=>"2016-11-21T12:21:59.875772-0700", :message=>"no value for epoch is set, defaulting to nil", :level=>:warn}
{:timestamp=>"2016-11-21T12:21:59.887529-0700", :message=>"no value for epoch is set, defaulting to nil", :level=>:warn}
{:timestamp=>"2016-11-21T12:21:59.994061-0700", :message=>"Created package", :path=>"gs-dashboards-1.0.2-1.x86_64.rpm"}
 + ls -altr`

When I use another CentOS 6 machine to test the installation, I receive this error:

`sudo rpm -ivh gs-dashboards-1.0.2-1.x86_64.rpm 
error: gs-dashboards-1.0.2-1.x86_64.rpm: headerRead failed: region trailer: BAD, tag 762079598 type 1970810215 offset -1853161472 count 16128
error: gs-dashboards-1.0.2-1.x86_64.rpm cannot be installed`

PS I also tried with yum install method

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://www.hostvirtual.com/kb/3402/rpmReadSignature-failed-region-trailer-BAD-tag-61-type-7-offset-48-count-16.html) suggests that the error is caused by different versions of yum and rpmbuild.

Since you use fpm, you should check which yum versions is compatible with.
I used fpm years ago, but I had problems with the non-standard spec files it generates; I ended up using rpmbuild.